# How can I get my URL's to look like www.example.com/1/product/date/price?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models:

```
Price :belongs_to Products
Product :has_many Prices
```

I created new Prices and I want to make the URL look a certain way, so in my `Price` model I put:

```
def to_param
    "#{id}/#{product.name}/#{purchase_date}/#{price}".parameterize
end
```

But, this gives me a URL like:

```
http://localhost:3000/prices/8-turkey-bacon-2012-01-16-2-58
```

When ideally I want it to be:

```
http://localhost:3000/8/turkey-bacon/2012-01-16/$2.58
```

Is there a way I can do this?

---

routes.rb - Price only

```
resources :prices do
  get ":id/:product_name/:purchase_date/:price" => "prices#show"
  get :autocomplete_product_name, :on => :collection
  post :create_multiple, :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: Try without the `parameterize`

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky That just throws a routing error when I hit the index page to see all prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to fix your `to_param` method, remove `parameterize` (as @yoavmatchulsky suggested). If it possible that `id`, `name`, `purchase_date`, or `price` could contain characters which are not allowed in a URL, do this:

```
require 'uri'

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    URI.encode("/#{id}/#{product.name}/#{purchase_date}/#{price}")
  end
end
```

Comment: For some reason this makes me get a `ActionController::RoutingError` saying that `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"prices"`. Also what about if I wanted to make the URI also `number_to_currency` like my views, is that possible?

Comment: Please post your routes in the question.

Comment: Which route is intended to match /:id/:product_name/:purchase_date/:price?

Comment: wrbg, I think you need to combine my answer and @jipiboily's. You are generating URLs in the form you want now, but you don't have any route to match them. (If this helps, I suggest you give an upvote to jipiboily too.)

Comment: Yeah I just tried his right now, but am unsure of where to put the route because when I put that in my `prices` block like `get ":id/:product_name/:purchase_date/:price" => "controller#action"
` it does nothing to the routes. When I added it with yours I still get the same routing error. My edit shows you what I did.

Comment: I can see the route when I `rake routes` but when I click on the `prices_path` for my view is goes back to `prices/8` only.

Comment: @wrbg, the URL you want to use for retrieving a Price does not conform to the conventions of Rails' RESTful `resources` routes. If you want to use a URL like this, the route should not be inside `resources :prices`. It should just be a plain `match` route. Also, don't use the `prices_path` helper -- it assumes you are using RESTful routes. Write your own helper method for getting the paths.

Comment: Just write something like: `def price_path(price); price.to_param; end`. Put that in ApplicationHelper. Use it in your views when generating links. (Note I added a leading / to the URLs generated by Price#to_param in my answer.)

Comment: Now my `edit` action doesn't work and looking at the routes I am unsure of the new route.It says this is invalid in my view: `edit_price_path(price)`.

Comment: I also notice that spaces are included, ex. `/Turkey Bacon` when it should be `/turkey-bacon`.

Comment: I also don't have to use anything in my routes after adding the helper method.

Comment: @wrbg, I already explained to you that the RESTful route helpers generated by `resources :prices` will *not* work if you want to have URLs like `/id/product_name/purchase_date/price` (which is what you said in your question). `edit_price_path`, `update_price_path`... all of them will not work. If you want to use URLs like this, you need to manually add your own routes, **NOT** use `resources :prices`. You also need to manually add your own path helpers. About spaces in the URL, did you use `URI.encode` as I showed in my answer? If so, there will be no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This could do it:

```
# in routes.rb

get ":id/:product_name/:purchase_date/:price" => "controller#action"
```

You can change get by whatever you need or add others (post, put...)

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Bates has a good screencast on [Pretty URLs with FriendlyId](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid). FriendlyId Gem will help you maintain and generate Friendly URLs

Comment: I did take a look at that but is it necessary in this case since I am still including the `price_id`? I figured it wasn't.

Comment: I guess not if this is the only place you need friendly URLs